# What happened To Lucius Fox?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

In *The Dark Knight Rises* when Batman leaves forever, what does Lucius Fox do? Does he retire? Or could he possibly have a new crime fighting-friend to help design technology and gadgets for?

Are there any **official sources** that tell us what happens to Lucius next?

Comment: There are obvious implications that Blake will be fighting crime in Gotham as some type of masked vigilante. But as to your specific question, there's nothing in the film from which we can draw an answer, and anything we put here would be pure speculation.

Comment: He falls on hard times. He has to resort to chauffeur work to make ends meet. Nolan is reportedly interested in filming a sequel exploring these ideas.

Comment: I wonder if Blake would become Robin... or Nightwing...

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Also, in the off hours from his chauffeur job, he is the president of the USA too.

Comment: Well, we know he gets thrown out a window when the Riddler finally snaps.

Comment: He actually retires to a faraway land, and uses his skills to become a Master Builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be taken into account that though Bruce Wayne went bankrupt in ‘The Dark Knight Rises’, his company remained functional (with a new board of course). And obviously Lucius will remain the CEO as derived from his last scene in which he talks to two technicians about the software patch for ‘the Bat’.

And as for possible future gadgets for Blake, thatz a long way off (as Blake has to train first and get accustomed to all Batman’s existing gadgets, and fighting). But since he knows that all Batman gadgets are from Bruce's company, he will not hesitate to ask for help from Lucius. And when the need arises,I am pretty sure that Fox won't hesitate to help Gotham's new superhero!

Comment: Blake really sucks when it comes to hand to hand combat, as shown in the movie!